# Is Google's Business Profile API accessible while waiting for Google's review?

Tags: google-api, google-business-profile-api, google-business-profile

I made a request to Google to use their Business Profile API, but the response from them can take up to two weeks. Is it possible to have access to a development version of the API so I can start coding and make tests without having to wait for their answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible, as per [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs#request-access) it is a requirement to get approval first.